# Is there a Visual Studio and TFS workflow that handles client library bundle/minification at TFS Build level

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, npm, nuget, bundle

I want to modernize my workflow of how I deal with client libraries (js, css, etc.) that I get via NPM or Bower.

1. I don't want to check client libraries into TFS source control.
2. When another developer downloads the project, their local Visual Studio and NPM/Bower will restore the libs to their workstation.  And of course they would not be able to check in to TFS any client library either.  Gotta keep Source Code repo clean.
3. When I do a local build, the local build will bundle and minify what I have locally.
4. When I check in my code and do a build at TFS, it would handle doing a NPM or Bower Restore there, and ALSO handle bundling and minification there.

Is that possible in the Visual Studio/TFS ecosystem?

I guess the same question can be asked of Nuget packages for server side things.

I imagine that I will have to do something with tfignore, and also somehow use a special build task (or PowerShell script) at TFS during build.

Is this overkill, or is this actually a normal, standard best practice?

Edit: versions I am using.
VS2015 Enterprise
TFS and TFS Build (on prem) 2015

Comment: Can you add some information? Which versions of Visual Studio and TFS? The answer details will differ: e.g. Build.vNext (VSTS or TFS 2015+) has an NPM task ready for use.

Comment: Yep, sorry updating now.

Comment: For bowser, you can use this extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=touchify.vsts-bower

Answer (score 1):

In your local machine:

1. You need to create a NPM **package.json** file for your project. And when you install NPM packages, add `"--save"` parameter. `"NPM install packageName --save"`.
2. Don't add those client libraries/packages to TFS source control. If you already added, you could delete them from TFS. Or use **[.tfignore](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/add-files-server#customize-which-files-are-ignored-by-version-control)** file to avoid them from being checked in.

In TFS build definition:

Add a [NPM](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/package/npm-install) build task and use this task to install those libraries when building on the build agent.In the step, you'd better specify a "**Working Directory**", the path is where your package.json file located. When this step runs, it will find the package.json file in the "Working Directory" and install those libraries defined in the package.json file.
[image]